# How to use Apple FamilyControls in ReactNative Expo Native Module

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, screen-time

I receive this error when importing FamilyControls in my Expo Native module

> [FamilyControls] Failed to get service proxy: Error
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named
> com.apple.FamilyControlsAgent" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection
> to service named com.apple.FamilyControlsAgent}

How can I use FamilyControls from Apple in my React Native Expo Application ?

Currently i try to import it like this in my react native expo module.

```
import ExpoModulesCore
import FamilyControls
public class ExpoScreenTimeApiModule: Module {
  
  public func definition() -> ModuleDefinition {
   let center = AuthorizationCenter.shared
    Name("ExpoScreenTimeApi")
    
      AsyncFunction("requestScreenTimePermission") { () -> String in
      let center = AuthorizationCenter.shared
      do {
        try await center.requestAuthorization(for: .individual)
        return "Permission Granted"
      } catch {
        throw error // This will be caught as a Promise rejection in JavaScript.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, by applying to the apple developer program. Furthermore I started the app via

> expo run:ios --device

selecting my physical device. Additionally I had to add Family Controls as capability in xCode.

Answer (score 0):

Family Controls framework is not part of the Expo modules, and it is not possible to use it directly in an Expo application.

The Family Controls framework is part of the Screen Time framework in macOS, which allows developers to access information about the user's screen time usage. This framework is not available in iOS or Android, and it is not possible to use it in a React Native Expo application.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. 

I do not want to use it as an expo module. I want to create my own native module prebuild it and use it in my expo application, as an expo native module, I think that should be possible, no?

On the docs I can see that FamilyControls is available from iOS 15.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/familycontrols

Current thought
'probably I have to add FamilyControls as capability in xCode, I will try this out'.